Piecewise linear EXTRApolation of a 3d dataset based on triangulation
Let's say we have a set of datapoints of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in general position.
I am trying to identify a natural way to define a continuous piecewise linear function (CPWL) $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that interpolates the dataset.
We know that we can apply a linear interpolation of the datapoints by applying a triangulation of the projected data on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and then by using the plane equation that describes each triangle.
But is there a natural way to extrapolate this CPWL function outside of the convex hull of the projected data?
Despite a thorough search, I could not find many papers addressing this.
MATLAB seems to have implemented a way to do this, but they do not describe the method.

Without some sort of model of, or constraints on, the exterior behaviour, extrapolation can be sketchy and misleading.
